# Is it unusual for kernel modules to access system calls?

Tags: linux

I am trying to find information on how a kernel module can access system calls, I can't seem to find a lot of information about this subject.

Is this because it is unusual for kernel modules to access system calls?

I guess it makes sense to be unusual for kernel modules to access system calls, because a kernel module is mostly used to implement a device driver, and why would a device driver need to access system calls (a device driver's job is to only communicate with an IO device)!

Answer (score 0):

System calls allow programs to call the kernel; they are not used by the kernel itself, or kernel modules.

When writing kernel code, you should use the appropriate [kernel APIs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/#kernel-api-documentation) directly.

Modules can do much more than drive a device: for example, file systems interact with the page cache, block layer, etc., not a physical device directly.